# Yoroi and Typhon return FeeTooSmallUtxo error when submitting transaction

Tags: plutus, yoroi, fee

I've been playing around with `cardano-serialization-lib` and building different types of transactions with `TransactionBuilder`. However, when I calculate fee and change using `add_change_if_needed(addr)` for a transaction, that interacts with a plutus script (in my case - the alwayssucceeds script, deployed on Testnet), I get the `FeeTooSmallUtxo` error, when submitting the transaction via `Yoroi` or `Typhon` wallet. At the same time, `Nami` wallet submits the tx without a problem. I am very confused as to why it is so.

Can anybody help me figure this out?

Here is a code snippet from a function that builds a transaction to send ADA to the contract address:

```
txBuilder.add_change_if_needed(shelleyChangeAddress);

let txBody = txBuilder.build();
let txHash = CardanoWasm.hash_transaction(txBody);

let witnesses = CardanoWasm.TransactionWitnessSet.new();
let transaction = CardanoWasm.Transaction.new(txBody, witnesses, undefined);

let witnessCBOR = await walletconnected.signTx(buf2hex(transaction.to_bytes()), true);
witnesses = CardanoWasm.TransactionWitnessSet.from_bytes(hex2buf(witnessCBOR));

transaction = CardanoWasm.Transaction.new(txBody, witnesses, undefined);
let trHash = await walletconnected.submitTx(buf2hex(transaction.to_bytes()));
```

And here is the error I get from `Yoroi`:

```
transaction submit error ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraBabbage 
(ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (UtxoFailure (FromAlonzoUtxoFail 
(FeeTooSmallUTxO (Coin 174125) (Coin 169901))))])
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the underlying version of cardano-node to which the transaction is being submitted. There was a recent bug on Testnet which looks to be related: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/4236

So this might not be related to your own code.